# Setting up default GridSortOrder with Vaadin8 and new Grid doesn't work

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin8

Our former solution based on Vaadin 7 Grid used multicolumn sorting. Data is sorted by backend database but we have to maintain visual infomation about sorting in column headers. Visualy it displays as small rectangles in column header.

Now with Vaadin 8 and new Grid, our data is, by default(by database), sorted by 'name' column so I'm defining default sort order for Grid using code as below. It seems to be straightforward but it doesnt show up on Grid. I can define GridSortOrder for one or two columns with no luck. Can't see anything on screen (in column headers). Any idea how to accomplish this properly?

```
List<GridSortOrder<Map>> orders=new ArrayList();
orders.add(new GridSortOrder<>(colName,SortDirection.DESCENDING));
grid.setSortOrder(orders);
```

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9135) opened regarding this functionality.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in 8.0.7 and 8.1.0.rc2